# How to center text in Gtk.Entry?

Tags: gtk#

I am trying to use an Gtk.Entry to show some text that is centered in a dialog. The entry is not editable. I would use a Gtk.Label, however I need to be able to select and copy the text to the clipboard.
Do I need to modify the Gtk.RcStyle? If so is there some example code for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go ahead and use a `Gtk.Label`, and set the [`Selectable`](http://docs.go-mono.com/monodoc.ashx?link=P%3aGtk.Label.Selectable) property to true.

Answer (score 0):

Use `xalign` property for centring text:

```
entry = Gtk.Entry()
entry.props.xalign = 0.5
```